# My TypeScript class is not defined. How do i fix it?

Tags: typescript, class, undefined

I recently started venturing into the world of TypeScript. My goal here is to create a simple game, whilst making use of **object orientated programming**. Starting off my first TypeScript project I've already encountered a problem I'm not sure how to fix. Could someone help me out?

This is my first class that will start off the game. As you can see class 'Game' doesn't have much in it, but the problem here is that the class 'Level' results in being *not defined.*

```
import { Level } from "./level.js"

class Game {
    
    private levels : Level[] 
    constructor() {
        //Level 1: using the word 'Bus'
        let level1 = new Level("B_s", "u", ["a", "u", "o", "i"])

        //Push the first level to an array
        this.levels.push(level1)
    }
}

new Game()
```

Here is the Level class:

```
export class Level {
    private word : string 
    private correctAnswer : string
    private possibilities : string[]
    /* Optional
        private score : number
        private difficulty : number */

    constructor(w : string, c : string, p : string[]) {
        this.word           = w
        this.correctAnswer  = c
        this.possibilities  = p
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure the export and import is written down correctly, but i might have missed something.

Comment: This code has errors—did tsc not report these when you tried to build your code? `Property 'levels' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` & `Property 'levels' is used before being assigned.`. You need to add `this.levels = []` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `import { Level } from "./level.js"` looks wrong. You should define TypeScript files as `*.ts`. Additionally, you should avoid using the file extension in your imports: `import { Level } from './level';`

As @jtbandes mentioned, the `levels` property is not being initialized.

```
// game.ts
import { Level } from './level';
export class Game {
  private levels: Level[];
  constructor() {
    this.levels = [];
    const level = new Level(/* ... */);
    this.levels.push(level);
  }
}
```

Or initialize the levels property in its definition. I tend to recommend against this because, personally, I like to initialize properties in the constructor, which allows for fun overloads in the constructor without the property having a default (slight run-time optimization).

```
export class Game {
  private levels: Level[] = [];
  // ...
}
```

You might also have some wrong configurations in your `tsconfig.json` (i.e. `include` array), but as for the actual TypeScript code these are the first things that stand out.

###### Aside

As a personal style choice, I like to define class files with the casing of the class, i.e. `Game.ts` and `Level.ts`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I initialized the levels property, as @jtbandes also said; but it didn't solve the problem right away. After some more digging online, I saw that I didn't add type='module' when defining the javascript src in my HTML file. This cleared the error for me.